# how to get the number from a variable in jinja dbt

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jinja2, dbt

I have this code, it takes max value from the table

```
{%- call statement('my_statement', fetch_result=True) -%}
      select max(CAST(updated AS bigint)) as val from table_1
{%- endcall -%}
{%- set my_var = load_result('my_statement')['data'] -%}

{{ return(my_var) }}
```

the return variable I have

```
[(Decimal('1655275144000'),)]
```

I am trying to get only the number from this variable. When I write like this, I have an error [image]

```
{%- set my_var = load_result('my_statement')['data'][0][0] -%}
```

although in python with importing the library it works great
[image]

How can I get this number in dbt with jinja

Comment: The error message is suggesting the call statement isn’t returning a value, which is why it returns `None`

Comment: @JoshD is there a problem of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a few different things going on here. Your code looks okay, and I couldn't reproduce your exact error. There are a few ways to go awry:

1. If you are using `load_result` inside of a model, or in a macro that gets called by a model, you need to wrap that in an `{% if execute %}` block; otherwise it can create parsing/compilation errors. See the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/getting-started/learning-more/using-jinja#dynamically-retrieve-the-list-of-payment-methods).
2. I want to be clear that you're evaluating `{%- set my_var = load_result('my_statement')['data'][0][0] -%}` in the same macro or model where you define `my_statement`?

Finally, I would recommend using the newer `run_query` macro, instead of the `call statement... load_result` pattern, since it's a little less confusing. See the [docs for `run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query)

Comment: agreed on run_query!

Comment: i can't seem to get an integer out of `run_query` either :\ .... keeps saying "TypeError: 'Undefined' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"